# Hamburger menu not working upon been clicked in react-typescript

Tags: tailwind-css, react-typescript

This is Sidebar.tsx component:

```js
    import { forwardRef } from "react";
    import { useMediaQuery } from "../../hooks/mediaQuery";
    import { SidebarData } from "../../types/index";
    import { useNavContext } from "../../containers/nav";

    import { Button } from "../button/Button";
    import { Input } from "../input/Input";
    import { Logout } from "../logout/Logout";
    import { NavItem } from "../navItem/NavItem";
    import { NewFeatures } from "../newFeatures/NewFeatures";
    import {
        Chart,
        Flag,
        Home,
        Layers,
        Search,
        Settings,
        Support,
        Task,
        Users,
    } from "../Icons";

    interface SidebarProps {
        // showNavbar: boolean;
    }

    const sidebarItems: SidebarData[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            label: "Home",
            icon: Home,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            label: "Dashboard",
            icon: Chart,
            count: 10,
        },
    
    ];

    const SideBar = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, SidebarProps>((props, ref) => {
    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery("(min-width:1060px)");
    const { nav, setNav } = useNavContext();

    return (
        <>
            <aside
                ref={ref}
                className=" lg:w-[280px] md:pb-10   bg-white shadow-sm md:px-3 absolute p-4 h-max md:sticky top-0 backdrop-blur-xl "
            >
                <div className="flex justify-between mb-4 mt-8 ">
                    {isDesktop && (
                        <img
                            src="/icons/untitled.png"
                            alt="logo"
                            width={143}
                            height={32}
                        />
                    )}
                    {!isDesktop && (
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => setNav(!nav)}
                            className="flex justify-end text-xl text-gray-500  w-full font-bold"
                            variant="ghost"
                        >
                            &times;
                        </Button>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="relative">
                    <div className="absolute top-5 left-4">
                        <Search fill="none" fontSize={"20px"} stroke="#667085" />
                    </div>
                    <Input type={"search"} placeholder="Search" />
                </div>

                {sidebarItems?.map(item => (
                    <NavItem
                        key={item.id}
                        label={item.label}
                        icon={item.icon}
                        count={item.count}
                    />
                ))}
                <NewFeatures />
                <Logout />
            </aside>
        </>
    );
    });

    SideBar.displayName = "SideBar";

    export default SideBar;
```

This is DashboardLayout.tsx component:

```js
    import { useMediaQuery } from "../../hooks/mediaQuery";
    import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
    import { useNavContext } from "../../containers/nav";
    import { Fragment, ReactNode } from "react";
    import { Button } from "../button/Button";
    import { Menu } from "../Icons";
    import SideBar from "../sidebar/Sidebar";

    import { SettingsTab } from '../../components/settingsTab/SettingsTab';

    interface DashboardLayoutProps {
        children: ReactNode;
    }
    export const DashboardLayout = ({ children }: DashboardLayoutProps) => {
    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery("(min-width:1060px)");
    const { nav, setNav } = useNavContext();
    return (
        <div className="flex bg-gray-50">
            <Transition
                as={Fragment}
                show={nav || isDesktop}
                enter="transform transition duration-[200ms]"
                enterFrom="-translate-x-full"
                enterTo="translate-x-0"
                leave="transform duration-[400ms] transition ease-in-out"
                leaveFrom="translate-x-0"
                leaveTo="-translate-x-full"
            >
                <SideBar />
            </Transition>
            <>
                <main className={`w-full transition-all duration-[200ms]`}>
                    {!isDesktop && (
                        <div className="px-6 py-4 items-center sticky top-0 bg-white">
                            <header className="flex justify-between">
                                <img
                                    src="/icons/untitled.png"
                                    alt="logo"
                                    width={143}
                                    height={32}
                                />
                                <Button variant="ghost" onClick={() => setNav(!nav)}>
                                    <Menu fill="none" fontSize={"26px"} stroke="#667085" />
                                </Button>
                            </header>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    <div
                        className={` md:px-4 py-5 min-h-full w-full ${nav && !isDesktop ? "hidden" : "block"
                            }`}
                    >
                        {children}{" "}
                        <div>
                            <SettingsTab
                                pageTitle={"Settings"}
                                pageSubTitle={"Manage your team and preferences here."} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </>
        </div>
    );
};
```

So I'm clicking on the hamburger svg icon and is not working meanwhile once the icon is clicked it is to show everything in Sidebar.tsx that's the dropdown and I'm using tailwindcss, don't know what might be the bug, because I've been on it for few hours. Please I don't know who could help me fix this.